# jquery UI - datepicker - setting a second one based on selection from first

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & jQuery-ui 1.10.3.  I have a page that will have 2 datepickers on it.  They will be used as a filter in selecting from a SQL table.  I'm reading a table row that has in it the `min` and `max` dates on the table.

`datepicker1` is the start date, `datepicker2` is the end date.  Using the `min` and `max` above, the calendar should begin in `datepicker1` with that date as the default, and `datepicker2` should have `max` as the most recent selectable date.  Those 2 dates serve as a hard beginning & end to the selectable dates on my calendar.  No date though has been set in the input box for either date.

What I need to do is that once the user makes a selection (in either of the `datepicker` controls), to enforce rules on the other `datepicker` based on that selection, but only if the other `datepicker` hasn't already been selected.

Once a date has been selected from one, the other (unselected) `datepicker` would have a pre-determined window of 14 days from the selected one (>= if `datepicker1` was selected first, <= if `datepicker2` was selected first) as its `max` (or `min`) date.  For example:

> Page loads, and minDate of 2012-12-10 & maxDate of 2013-10-22 is
>   returned from query. `datepicker1` has the 12/10 date as it's
>   "beginning" (farthest day back that can be selected). `datepicker2`
>   has 10/22/2013 date as its "end" (newest day that can be selected).
>
> User clicks on calendar control in `datepicker1` and selects
>   2013-02-14.
>
> Now, `datepicker2` would re-calculate its new maxDate, to
>   be 14 days after 2013-02-14.
>
> User then can select any date >= 2013-02-14 through 2013-02-28 as 
>   an end date.
>
> Process would be reversed if `datepicker2` was selected first.

The options on each datepicker are pretty much the same for both:

```
    $(function(){
      $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        buttonImage: "calendar-blue.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Choose Start Date",
        showOn: "both",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                $(".ui-datepicker").addClass("resizeDP");
                },
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                $(".ui-datepicker").removeClass("resizeDP");
                }
  });
});
```

I can enforce the `max` and `min` dates on the calendars when the page is loaded, but can't make the "new" 14 day one apply when it is selected.  I've tried several different ways (mostly in the `onClose`) but can't make any of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 $("#datepicker2").click(function(){
     if($("#datepicker1").val() != ""){
       $(this).datepicker("destroy");
       $(this).datepicker({
         //initialize datepicker2 based on datepicker1 value 
       });
       $(this).datepicker("show");
    }   
 });
```

And vice versa.

Note i'm not sure if the date picker opens up before the on click event.  But you could always do it on the `mouse down` or even `blur` event of Datepicker1 to set Datepicker2 etc..

Comment: @steve_o please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks